# Simple excel filter using data validation as criteria

Tags: validation, filter, dashboard

This should be simple but I can't find the right solution. I'm trying to create a simple summary dashboard where a user just needs to select criteria (dropdown list) and the array will be filtered based on those criteria selected.

This should be similar to a filter dropdown for table headers but instead of doing it by each header, you will just select from a data-validated list the criteria you want. So essentially, for two criteria, you have two boxes with data validation. I've tried =FILTER function but the returned values cannot be clicked nor read on the formula bar. The same with INDEX-MATCH/XLOOKUP combination. I have links included in the cells so I want to have them still clickable after the filter criteria are applied.

Please note that I'm using Excel on Mac but if there's a way to do it in Windows, that will help too! Also, I'm trying to avoid VBA as this should also work on online versions.

Thanks so much!

I've tried =FILTER function but the returned values cannot be clicked nor read on the formula bar. The same with INDEX-MATCH/XLOOKUP combination. I have links included in the cells so I want to have them still clickable after the filter criteria are applied.